# Does the latest version of blender work with python 2.7?

Tags: python, blender

Does blender 2.60a work with python 2.7?

when i launch blender it shows me

```
found bundled python 2.7 in program file...something like this...
```

but on the blender site it says that i must have python 3.2, so how did that happen?

Comment: see [python 2.x or 3.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253430)

Comment: @NickDandoulakis I'm not asking about the difference between 2.x and 3.x I know the difference but my question is how come blender work with 2.7? for example the older version is written for python 2.6.5 if you use python 2.7 with that version it won't work...

Comment: ok but if v2.60a requires Python 3.x then you'll have to install it.

Comment: @NickDandoulakis yes but read this questiion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392689/python-3-2-doesnt-work-with-python-2-7  - and the weird this is that it seems to detect  python 2.7 i'm just asking how is this possible

Comment: I found this http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Python/API/Py3.1_Migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of Blender only work with Python 3.  For this reason they give you a full copy of a Python version that they know will work.  If you wanted to run Blender with a 2.x version of Python you would have to convert the source and modules to 2.x compatible code and then recompile.

Your system may have a 2.x version, but Blender will still use its own.  Keep in mind that your using an [Alpha version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_software#Alpha)... it wouldn't be all that supprising if it doesn't work how it should.

If you want to test which version it's using, write a simple script inside Blender, like this:

```
print "If you're using 3.x this will give an error"
```

Comment: looks like you're right python console won't open anyway... i guess i have to find a way to install python 3.2

Comment: You don't have to install Python 3.x separately. Latest versions of Blender come with Python interpreter built in.

Comment: @someonelikeme: to check the console on blender from win you have to go Window-->"Toggle System Console"